# What is the term for something you didn’t know you needed until you’ve had it?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

> I didn’t think I needed lotion until I used some, and now I need it.

— is the MOST basic example of the situation I’m talking about;
not realizing something was necessary or essential until you’ve tried it.

e.g., looking to use this word for title, brand, etc.

Comment: **_addictive_**

Comment: **learning** - after all, we start out knowing nothing. We don't even know that we are hungry until... hey, what is that loud noise? Damn, someone is crying. Wait. It's me. Shoot.

Comment: "People want this. They just don't know it yet." - Steve Jobs, before Apple released the iPad

Comment: "I didn’t think I needed lotion until I used some, and now I need it." could have several meanings. "Need" suggests some kind of necessity, but it can mean "strongly want", or it can denote various degrees of how necessary something is (often it is relative to a specific goal or task). Will your skin be a bit rougher, will you be a bit unhappier, will you lose some of your identity, will you die?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, a ***revelation***

> Something that surprises you
>
> A pleasant often enlightening surprise
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revelation)
>
> Something revealed or disclosed, especially a striking disclosure, as of something not before realized.
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/revelation)

Answer (score -1):

Enlightenment
Realization
Understanding
Revelation

Revealing
Exposing
Uncovering

Comprehending
Transitioning
Accepting
Realizing

Processing
Evaluating
Polarizing
Dividing
Separating
Contrasting

Relative Perseption
Hidden / Seen
Forming awareness
Change in perspective
Experience the difference
Before and after

Exposure to something, in contrast to or beyond the limits of what you currently believe and/or have consciously witnessed or experienced.

Undergoing testing, and finding something proves helpful or remains true, and forming a desire, dependency, wanting, liking, or acceptance of it.

I was wondering the same thing. This is the best I can offer, based off of root word definition researching. And contemplating it all day. I believe it’s a multifaceted question, with time being relative, referring to the exposure of, the testing of, the evaluation of, the forming of one’s own personal belief, the conclusion of, a memory of, or attempt to convince someone to believe something and commit to action, before they have taken the conscious actions necessary to have formed the believe for themselves.

Which could also be summarized as exposure, application, evaluation, realization, conclusion, reflection, and faith.

There may be more accurate words to help describe this process as well. I find it difficult to completely define into one word, but breaking down the concept of the experience can be a helpful process of forming a deeper understanding of the topic at hand. Allow the mind to find new ways to approach the question, or form a new one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please [edit] to focus your answer on one suggestion and flesh that out. (If you need an example, the other answer has done this by citing a dictionary.) You have way too many suggestions here and many of them don't make any sense.